# If in a class implements an interface and at the same extends another class, can we declare a constructor for the class with super keyword?

Tags: java

The compiler is not accepting the constructor as a constructor but as a method and giving the following remark:

My piece of code:

```
class  Rsesults  extends  Mark  implements  Sports {

Results(int x,int y) {

   super(x,y);

}
```

The error:

```
invalid method declaration; return type required

Results(int x, int y)
```

Comment: `Results` should be `Rsesults  `

Comment: @FastSnail I'm pretty sure the class name is the typo here... but that would work fine from a code perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Your class and your constructor have different names :  **Rsesults**   - **Results**

Which means that Java doesn't recognize  **Results** as constructor, but thinks that it's a general method ( which means it has to have a return type  )